# Manually interpolating NAs in large dataset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I am currently working on a project that uses Pandas, with a large dataset (~42K rows x 1K columns).

My dataset has many omissing values which I want to interpolate to obtain a better result when training an ML model using this data. My method of interpolating the data is by taking the average of the previous and the next value and then considering that the value for any `NaN`. Example:

```
TRANSACTION   PAYED   MONDAY   TUESDAY   WEDNESDAY
D8Q3ML42DS0   1       123.2    NaN       43.12
```

So in the above example the `NaN` would be replaced with the average of the 123.2 and 43.12 which is 83.16. If the value can't be interpolated then a 0 is put. I was able to implement this in a number of ways but I always end up getting into the issue of it taking a very long time to process all of the rows in the dataset despite running it on an Intel Core i9. The following are approaches I've tried and have found out that they take too long:

- Interpolating the data and then only replacing the elements that need to be replaced instead of replacing the entire row.
- Replacing the entire row with a new `pd.Series` that has the old and the interpolated values. It seems like my code is able to execute reasonably well on a `Numpy Array` but the slowness comes from the assignment.

I'm not quite sure why the performance of my code comes nowhere close to `df.interpolate()` despite it being the same idea. Here is some of my code responsible for the interpolation:

```py
for transaction_id in df.index:
    df.loc[transaction_id, 2:] = interpolate(df.loc[transaction_id, 2:])
```

```py
def interpolate(array:np.array):
    arr_len = len(array)
    for i in range(array):
        if math.isnan(array[i]):

            if i == 0 or i == arr_len-1 or math.isnan(array[i-1]) or math.isnan(array[i+1]):
                array[i] = 0
            else:
                statistics.mean([array[i-1], array[i+1]])
    
    return array
```

My understanding is that Pandas has some sort of parallel techniques and functions that it is able to use to perform that. How can I speed this process up even a little?

Comment: 1) your current code does not run (`df.loc[transaction_id, 2:]` and `range(array)`)    2) if you fix these errors it'll be slow due to the python loops (`for transaction_id in df.index` and `for i in len(array)`)    3) why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Just use `df.interpolate()` like ihatecoding's answer. You have nothing to gain by reinventing the wheel manually.

Comment: You might find the "Enhancing performance" pandas user guide useful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html

Answer (score 1):

```
df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
```

Try doing this it might help.

Comment: While I understand what you and SMCI are saying, may of the previous research done on the area I am currently working on has shown a lot of good results by using this method of interpolation. So, its not me trying to 'reinvent the wheel', more like me trying to experiment with the findings made in other research papers.